# Keystroke delays at random times while accessing esxi environment through teamviewer

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer, esxi, delay, keystrokes

Hey All,

So, let me explain my problem. I've got an VMWare ESXi lab environment at home, it is assigned a Free license.

I have one Windows 10 VM set up as Management VM with the Teamviewer 11 client installed that is started when the machine boots. When I'm not at home and want to manage some things on my environment I wake my ESXi-machine with WOL and when it boots, the Windows 10 Manegement VM with teamviewer is also booted. This way I can take it over via Teamviewer and manage everything via the regular vSphere client.

This is where my question comes in; I regularly notice keystroke delays in the machines I try to manage via the vSphere client. This is not happening all the time though, in most cases the keystrokes have no delay at all. Still it's quite anoying when it happens.

When I'm at home locally, connecting to the management VM via RDP and accessing the vSphere client from that session never gives any keystroke delays. Also, while connected via teamviewer to my Windows 10 Management VM, there is absolutely no delay noticeable in the Windows 10 VM at all. Just at random times, while managing other guests via the vSphere client. Sometimes rebooting solves the problem immediately, sometimes it doesn't.

Also when I start a RDP session, from within the Teamviewer session to the Windows 10 VM, to one of the machines I try to manage with keystroke delays at that moment, the delay is gone. Switching back to the vSphere client gives the delay back until some random time the delay stops and the keystrokes are accurate. So one could suspect this is because of the vSphere client...

However, since it's not happening all the time, I'm really curious to find out why this is happening and even better, solve the root cause.

Anyone got any ideas? Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/11202/disable-teamviewer-from-stealing-port-80) and see if it helps you.

Comment: I have checked it out but I'm pretty confident this is not causing my problems. One could expect the delay was persistant if this was the case, which it isn't. Thanks for this though.